# Add temporary entry to hosts, when tunnelling SSH

Tags: mac-osx, ssh-tunnel, hosts

When outside our company firewall, I use a script to tunnel via SSH and expose our internal wiki to my OSX machine. Is there a command to temporarily tell OSX to resolve to my local port when the tunnel is set up?

The sequence I'm hoping to use is:

1. open the tunnel

   `ssh -f external-proxy.example -L 8001:internal-wiki.example:8000 -N`
2. [DO SOMETHING HERE]
3. typing the URL **internal-wiki.example:8000** in my browser causes it to transparently view **localhost:8001**

Other details:

- I could edit **/etc/hosts** but that would be a persistent change. I want to use this only when outside
- We're not using SSL or certs.

Comment: I can think of a solution involving a `tun` device which would work on Linux. Does Mac OS X have a `tun` device that can be used in a similar way?

Comment: Check my answer as it meets everything you've asked for without any extra steps on creating tun devices, fifo nor proxies.

Comment: @marcel yes it is a good answer. It's the same as the first option I gave, wrapped in a bash script. I do like the use of trap, btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a solution for you, wrap your ssh command into a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function control_c {
    echo -en "\n## Caught SIGINT; Clean up /etc/hosts and Exit \n"
    sed -i '' "/internal-wiki/d" /etc/hosts
    exit $?
}

trap control_c SIGINT
trap control_c SIGTERM

(sleep 5; open http://internal-wiki.example:8001 &)&
echo '127.0.0.1 internal-wiki.example' >> /etc/hosts
ssh -L8001:internal-wiki.example:8000 -f external-proxy.example -N
```

Explaining:

1. function that executes the cleanup on Control-C when issued
2. trap Control-C and shutdown
3. sleep, tell osx to open your site, get out of the way (the
   ampersand)
4. adds the entry to `/etc/hosts`
5. create the tunnel
6. when you ctrl-c, the functions kicks in and cleans up `/etc/hosts`
   with the transient entry

Comment: Oh, you'll have to `sudo script.bash` in order to be able to edit `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 2):

My apologies if this is not sufficient for an *answer*, I don't have enough rep to comment here.

I think **/etc/hosts** is possibly the best option. I don't know what your teardown process is, but you could add removing the `/etc/hosts` entry as part of it.
Also I think the port change won't work with a `/etc/hosts` solution. Can you map `localhost:8000` to `internal-wiki.example:8000`?

Then you could add something like `127.0.1.1 internal-wiki.example` to `/etc/hosts` and remove the line when you stop the tunnel like so: `sed -i '' '/127.0.1.1 internal-wiki.example/d'` (be sure to test that before running live of course).

This should allow you to use `http(s)://internal-wiki.example:8000` in your browser.

It's not a perfect solution, but anything better (such as port mapping) I think would require an http proxy running locally.

For what it's worth, adding and removing host entries is how Parallels makes VMs addressable by hostname. This is added to my `/etc/hosts` while my `xu17` VM is running: `172.20.10.112   xu17.shared xu17 #prl_hostonly shared`

Of course running an [nginx proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) would handle this nicely, but it might be a bit more setup than you're looking for?
A simpler option with netcat might work depending on the web application.

```
# make fifo for second nc to transfer response back to first nc
mkfifo /tmp/proxy.pipe
nc -lk 8001 < /tmp/proxy.pipe | nc internal-wiki.example 8000 > /tmp/proxy.pipe
```

Then when you close the tunnel, you can kill the `nc` process and delete `/tmp/proxy.pipe`

Answer (score 2):

Create temporary hosts entry:

```
rm /tmp/hosts
cp /etc/hosts /tmp/hosts
echo "127.0.0.1 example.com" >> /tmp/hosts
mount --bind /tmp/hosts /etc/hosts
```

Remove temporary hosts entry (and return persistent hosts file):

```
umount -f /etc/hosts
```

or reboot or shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Run a load balancing web server on your Mac balancing between the localhost forwarding and the real address of the wiki configured to prefer the localhost forwarding address.

When the ssh connection is down the load balancer will notice and direct your
connections to the regular wiki address.

Configure  your web browser to proxy connections for the wiki via the load balancer.

Somewhat of a sledgehammer to crack a nut though.

Answer (score 0):

Name services (DNS, ldap, /etc/hosts) do not "resolve ports" they resolve hostnames. This statement is not entirely true but a proper explanation at this point is irrelevant and time consuming.

Since OSX uses a BSD kernel, I guess it may also "borrow" a lot of other code from there. The files ns resolver defaults to reading from /etc/hosts but this can be overridden on Linux and BSD by setting the HOSTALIASES environment variable (in the shell you start the browser from) but this only works if there is no '.' in the name. If you can use urls without a . in the name this will solve your problem.

Alternatively, you could run a script to configure port redirection to reroute packets addressed to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000 to 127.0.0.1:8001 and conversely on incoming packets. But this is rather a kludgy solution.

Alternatively you could install squid and use a custom url redirector to rewrite the requests (also possible if you start using https -but tricky).

A much cleaner option would be to run a proper tunnelled connection across the ssh. I believe this is not supported by osx out of the box but there are [openvpn compliant add ons for osx](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/how-to-set-up-an-os-x-openvpn-client/)

If it were me I would just set up scripts to swap around the hosts file, keeping all the traffic on one port and making sure that the default config is swapped in at boot time and when the ssh connection ends.

Comment: Not true, check this out: ```A Service record (SRV record) is a specification of data in the Domain Name System defining the location, i.e., the hostname and port number, of servers for specified services. It is defined in RFC 2782, and its type code is 33.```

Comment: Sort of true - but only in DNS and I've yet to see something actually implementing this to resolve a port number.

Comment: Well, not for browsers or any service with already predefined ports. But if you need to use non standard sockets, then you could build your system to search for the pertinent SRV record to figure out where to bind to. It's there in the specification, it's not mandatory for the web, but still, there are ways.